# Sanitize a string column with a mix of datetime and timestamps

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp, hubspot

I have a column on BigQuery of String datatype that has a mix of date and timestamps as strings.
https://www.evernote.com/l/AmOc0thoaMRLJ7y1IFnLMxwLAeREujUtGRc

Tried SAFE_CAST, DATE_PARSE but neither work.

I want to be able to query this column uniformly as timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to query this column uniformly as timestamps.

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT close_date, 
  COALESCE(
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(SAFE_CAST(close_date AS INT64)),
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%y', close_date)
  ) AS close_date_as_timestamp
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to your sample data - result is

```
Row close_date      close_date_as_timestamp  
1   1556064000000   2019-04-24 00:00:00 UTC  
2   01/24/19        2019-01-24 00:00:00 UTC  
3   1548892800000   2019-01-31 00:00:00 UTC  
4   11/27/18        2018-11-27 00:00:00 UTC
```

Note: You can add to COALESCE as many different patterns as you expect in your data

For example you can add below to support `2019-01-01`

```
SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', close_date)
```

And so on ...